# Getting a jenkinsfile stage to run on master branch and tag

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I tried to get a stage to run when user push to master branch or push a tag to origin. This is the `when` condition that i set in the stage:

```
  when {
    expression {
      branch 'master' || tag 'v*'
    }
  }
```

It throws an error that `No such field found: field org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.UninstantiatedDescribable v*`. Is there another way to do a conditional expression in such a way that it works?

Comment: Are you building a tag?

Comment: no. I want the stage to run on 2 conditions: when branch is master or when tag is v1.0.0

Comment: AFAIU, there are tags in your repository but you're not building tags — you're building a branch. When the branch you build _just so happens_ to be also tagged, you want your condition to catch that?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Jenkinsfile to automate the process to build a docker image and push it to the docker registry. In this example the docker image is build when someone push a tag in master branch:

```
stage('Master Docker Prepare') {
      when {
        expression {
                      return (env.BRANCH_NAME=="master" && env.GIT_TAG!=null && env.GIT_TAG != '')
                   }
      }
      steps {
        echo 'Deploying'
        script {
            dockerImage = docker.build DOCKER_REGISTRY_PUT+"/"+DOCKER_IMAGE + ":" + env.GIT_TAG
        }
        script {
            docker.withRegistry( 'http://'+DOCKER_REGISTRY_PUT, DOCKER_REGISTRY_CREDENTIAL ) {
                        dockerImage.push()
            }
        }
   }
}
```

I think you can make something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use *anyOf* inside *when* as shown below

```
when { 
   anyOf { 
        branch 'master'
        expression { tag =~ 'v*' }
         } 
}
```